# SQL Query to get result form multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have many to many relationship between two of my tables t1 and t2. I am trying to get results from t1 that belongs to a t2, I can with a simple join, but I also want to get all the t2 records that have the relationship to that t1 row.

I'll translate the result i am looking for to json for better understanding:

```
[
    {
        "name": "t1.1",
        "t2s": [
            {
                "name": "t2.1"
            },
            {
                "name": "t2.2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "t1.2",
        "t2s": [
            {
                "name": "t2.1"
            },
            {
                "name": "t2.3"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

UPDATE:
this is my current query, which return me data for the relationship, but I am also looking to get all the t2 records that have relationship with t1.

```
select t1.name,t2.name 
from t1 
join t1_t2 as t1t2 
  on t1t2.id=t1.id 
where t1t2.id = '10'
```

[image: db structure]

Comment: whats in the list of relations? JSON is not always readable,not in your case atleast. Please provide table structure and expected output along with relations.

Comment: There must be better way to get this done but you can try subquery if thats ok for you:-Select 
(Select name from t1 where t1.id=A.t1_id) t1Name,
(Select name from t2 where t2.id=A.t2_id) t2Name
From t1_t2 A

Comment: Also give a try to:SELECT
    T1.Name,
    T2.Name
FROM
    T1_T2 Mapping
    JOIN T1  On T1.Id=Mapping.T1_Id
    JOIN T2 On T2.Id=Mapping.T2_Id

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Show us sample data and desire output.  `all the t2 records` is very vague. You also can provide a [**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/256da/8) we can find an answer much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand the goal is here. If you are trying to pull `t1.name` and `t2.name` for some `t1_t2` row, the following query will do it:

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.name
FROM t1_t2
JOIN t1
  on t1_t2.t1_id = t1.id
JOIN t2
  on t1_t2.t2_id = t2.id
WHERE t1_t2.id = 10
```

Here I simply join `t1`, where the ids are equal, than do the same for `t2`. If that is all you need, it is pretty straightforward.

If on the other hand, you want all `t2.name` associated with a `t1`, you just need to change the `WHERE`:

```
WHERE t1.id = 10
```

This will get you all the rows that have an association with the t1 row.

Might I suggest a different, simpler table structure:

```
t1:
  id
  t1_t2_id
  name
t2:
  id
  t1_t2_id
  name
t1_t2:
  id
```

See, here I make the two tables point to the many-to-many table. Then you could just skip the t1_t2 table completely and say:

```
SELECT t2.name FROM t2
JOIN t1
ON t1.t1_t2_id = t2.t1_t2_id
WHERE t1.id = 10
```